# web2py: sqlform dropdown without submit and form actions

Tags: python, web2py

This is a bit outside of my understanding of web2py and SQLFORMS. I have 5 separate named dropdown SQLFORMS that are accessing the same db table information. I want the user to just pick an option on the dropdown and that would be it, no submit button. When they pick an option I want another dropdown SQLFORMS to be generated to the page.

Here is the code:

```
def deck():

form1 = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s', orderby=db.tbl_card.id)))
form1.process(formname='form1')

form2 = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s', orderby=db.tbl_card.id)))
form2.process(formname='form1')

form3 = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s', orderby=db.tbl_card.id)))
form3.process(formname='form1')

form4 = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s', orderby=db.tbl_card.id)))
form4.process(formname='form1')    

form5 = SQLFORM.factory(Field('cards', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_card.id', '%(name)s', orderby=db.tbl_card.id)))
form5.process(formname='form1')

#form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('evo', requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'tbl_evo.id', '%(evo_type)s', orderby=db.tbl_evo.id)))
#form2.process(formname='form2')

return dict(form1=form1,form2=form2,form3=form3,form4=form4,form5=form5)
```

How do I remove the submit button?

How do I create an action or generate a dropdown SQLFORM based on the option that was picked?

Thank you so much

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you are doing and would help if you show some code. Note, a SQLFORM is not a dropdown -- it is a server-side representation of an entire form. It may *contain* `<select>` dropdowns as well as other widgets.

Comment: That is what I have so far. This generates drop downs of the card table with a submit button. I want the user to be able to select an option without the submit button. When the user selects an option I want a new form (the commented out form) to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DAL` table that includes a `Field` with an `IS_IN_DB` or `IS_IN_SET` validator as its "requires" attribute, when you create a SQLFORM based on that table, the field will be represented with a `<select>` element. For example:

```
db.define_table('mytable', Field('myfield',
    requires=IS_IN_DB(db, 'othertable.otherfield')))
form = SQLFORM(db.mytable)
```

The above will generate a complete HTML form, including a submit button. If you don't want the whole form but just want the `<select>` element for a particular field, you have two options:

Extract the element from the full form:

```
select = form.element('select[name=myfield]')
```

Alternatively, you can skip creating the full form and just directly create the select element:

```
select = SQLFORM.widgets.options.widget(db.mytable.myfield,
                                        db.mytable.myfield.default)
```

Once you have the select element on the page, you can use Javascript to detect selections and take whatever action you want:

```
<script>
jQuery('select[name=myfield]').on('change', function() {
  [do something here]
});
</script>
```

Comment: I tried both methods you pointed out regarding select. I am calling them inside of my controller def deck() like so: 
select = form.element('select[name=name]') and returning dict(select=select). The page just shows 'None'

Comment: I made the first method work. Is there a way to do it without creating another table? 

Inside the JavaScript [do something here] can I call web2py code? How would I generate the other form I want to create? 

Thanks

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do -- maybe post about this on the [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/web2py) where it will be easier to discuss? Please indicate exactly what you are trying to achieve in terms of the UI and workflow (and give some details about your data model). And no, you cannot call web2py code within the Javascript -- web2py code is Python and runs on the server -- Javascript runs in the browser. However, you can use Javascript to make Ajax calls to web2py, and you can use web2py templates (written in Python) to generate Javascript code.

Comment: I posted my question there but I think it has to be approved first? Anyways, I appreciate all the answers you provide to all of my questions. Is there a way I could contact you to discuss what I mean? Thanks again

Comment: I don't see any messages pending approval -- can you try posting it there again?